# Connecting HDP from Teradata Studio Express 15.10

Tags: hadoop, hive, teradata, hcatalog

I've been trying to connect my HDP cluster(2.1) from Teradata Studio Express 15.10 via Knox but couldn't succeed. All the configurations namely the JDBC hostname, port, user/password, WebHCat host,port I'm providing as correct. The JDBC connection is working perfectly if I test it from the beeline shell.

```
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:10000
scan complete in 11ms
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:10000
Enter username for jdbc:hive2://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:10000: hive
Enter password for jdbc:hive2://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:10000: ****
Connected to: Apache Hive (version 0.13.0.2.1.2.2-516)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 0.13.0.2.1.2.2-516)
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
```

However I don't find my conviction on WebHCat username it's asking of. Not sure what's the default one for HDP or how a new one could be defined. The custom `webhcat-site.xml` properties `"webhcat.proxyuser.hue.groups"` & `"webhcat.proxyuser.hue.hosts"` won't help me out here.

When I try the connectivity from Teradata Studio Express GUI, it gives the following error:

```
java.lang.Exception: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:10000/default?hive.server2.transport.mode=http;hive.server2.thrift.http.path=cliservice: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:10000 refused
    at com.teradata.datatools.hadoop.hive.connectivity.HiveConnection.openJdbcConnection(HiveConnection.java:286)
    at com.teradata.datatools.hadoop.hive.connectivity.HiveConnection.createConnection(HiveConnection.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
    at com.teradata.datatools.hadoop.hive.connectivity.HiveConnection.open(HiveConnection.java:144)
    at com.teradata.datatools.hadoop.hive.connectivity.HivePingFactory.createJdbcConnection(HivePingFactory.java:44)
    at com.teradata.datatools.hadoop.hive.connectivity.PingJdbcJob.createTestConnection(PingJdbcJob.java:30)
    at com.teradata.datatools.hadoop.hive.connectivity.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Anybody got any idea on what's happening here? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by *"WebHCat username"*? With JDBC you just provide your end-user credential *(user/pwd or Kerberos TGT)* and that's all. The way HiveServer2 talks to the Metastore is defined server-side. And AFAIK it does not use HCatalog -- because HCat is actually the interface offered to programs external to the Hive project (i.e. Pig, Spark, whatever)

Comment: Ah, maybe you are confusing HiveServer2 (the JDBC service) and WebHCat (the REST interface to HCatalog). They are different beasts, use different protocols, and different hots/ports!!

Comment: Yes Samson, it appears I was mixing these two. But via Teradata Studio Express, when you start the connection, the 2 things it asks for is WebHCat server name, port & user. And the other information is regarding JDBC connection i.e., the server, port, user, password.
So, yes I am mixing these 2 but it's basically the software that needs these infos to connect to. 
Any help?

Comment: **1.** where do you run your `beeline` command - from inside the cluster, or from the same machine you run Taratata Studio? **2.** did you put the same exact URL in `beeline` and Studio (incl. the HTTP settings)? **3.** did you feed the "host:port" for the actual HiveServer2 *(which cannot be accessed from outside the cluster)*  or for the KNOX gateway??

Comment: **4.** Are you sure the KNOX connection is HTTP and not HTTPS *(with an extra SSL option in the URL)*?!

Comment: For the time being, I left Knox out of question. And was testing JDBC conenection only from TD Studio Express. It's not getting connected as well. 
The connectivity is well established from command prompt:
curl -s 'http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:50111/templeton/v1/ddl/database?user.name=hive'
{"databases":["default","table_1","table_2"]}

Not able to connect via the tool.And like I mentioned in the question above as well, the "WebHCat User Name" is something I'm not getting. A mandatory field in the tool that needs to be filled in. Anything on this?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment above.
1) The beeline command run from inside the cluster, not from the machine where TD Studio is installed.
2) Yes, the beeline URL & the one generated in Studio after putting in the details are the same.
3) Yes, the host:port is of actual hiveserver2 only. But as I mentioned above, I'm leaving Knox out of this for now. Atleast until I resolve the JDBC connectivity.

Comment: Any chance there is a **firewall** between your client machine and the cluster, that is blocking TCP traffic on port 10000? Can you get at the HiveServer2 logs to check whether your connection got through but was rejected? And can you run a `netstat` on your client machine, just after trying to connect, to see if you can still see a trace of an *established* communication (at least one TCP packet got through), or not?

Comment: The hiveserver2 logs, guess some problem there. The thrift server seems not responding. 
`server.ThreadPoolServer.java:run(215)) - Error during processing of message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException`

I checked and modified the property `"hive.server2.authentication"` to `NOSASL` in `hive-site.xml`

Doesn't help. There's no Kerberos authentication on cluster so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this issue resolved.

There were couple of configs that were needed to be taken care of within TD Studio Express 15.10:

For JDBC:

```
Hostname, Port Number (10000 or 10001 or any other on which the hive service is listening), JDBC User Name, JDBC Password & uncheck "HTTP Transport Mode" from the options list in the tool.
```

For WebHCat:

```
WebHCat Hostname, Port Number(50111 or the one on which HCat is listening) & WebHCat User Name (hue)
```

Lastly, the firewall configurations should be such that it won't be blocking the HCat port.